# Python / Pandas - get_group that has partial string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
name   . profession
Alex   . Data Analyst
Markus . Sales Manager
Carlos . Credit Analyst
Otavio . HR Manager
...
```

I need to know how many people in this dataframe has the string "Analyst" in its profession. The answer should be 2.

I'm trying to use `groupby` and `get_group`, however I'm not finding the right way to put that into the `get_group` syntax.

Right now I'm here:

```
df.groupby('profession').get_group(???).agg('count')
```

Can someone advise what would be the right syntax or suggest another way to do it?

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that in general you can't get_group for a substring. What you can do is get by a trie or something, it most cases the .str.contains will be faster (though it is O(n) which may be an issue), but if you are recalculating for many 'needles' it could be worth indexing the groupby keys (e.g. with a trie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the scalar answer, you can use this command:

```
df.profession.str.contains('Analyst').sum()
```

Output:

```
2
```

Or as a dataframe with `groupby`:

```
df.assign(is_analyst = df.profession.str.contains('Analyst'))\
  .groupby('is_analyst')['name']\
  .size()
```

Output:

```
is_analyst
False    2
True     2
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great Scott. That's the answer. Is there a way to include an OR in the sentence (like str.contains("analyst" OR "magician")?

Comment: @abutremutante Yes, using regex in the `pat` parameter in `contains` method.  `df.profession.str.contains('Analyst|Magician')`

Comment: @abutremutante could you please accept this awesome answer :-)

Comment: Definitely! I was just waiting for the minimum time.